# Group theory - subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)\,$ be a group where $\,n \geq 2$ and $d \neq 0$.

Find all possible values for $d$ and $n$ so that $\{0,d\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know that for subset of $G$ to be a group there needs to be a closure under the addition operation.

So: $\,d+d = 2d\,$ belongs to $\,\{0,d\}$.

So $2d=0$.

But the problem is I'm not sure how to generalize this and to find all possible values for $\,d\,$ and $\,n\,$.

Comment: Title is not well descriptive.

Comment: @BabakSorouh - For a first post I would say that its a good title, its very hard to give titles to questions at first

Comment: @Anna yes I learned Theorem of Lagrange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(1)$ $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is cyclic and has a subgroup of order $m$ only if $m$ divides $n$ (by the theorem of Lagrange).

$(2)$ Any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

$(3)$ In your problem, any subgroup of the form $D\le G = \{0, d\}$ $d\ne 0$, $d \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ clearly has order $2$ and must be cyclic, so $D = \langle d \rangle$.

So yes, $d+d = 0$, and hence $d^{-1} = -d = d$, otherwise $|\langle d\rangle| = \{0, d\}\ne 2$.

By $(1)$, $|\langle d \rangle| = 2$ must divide $n.\;$ So $\;n = 2k\;$ where k is some positive integer. Hence $n$ must be even.

Now, what can you say about the possible element $d$ such that $d$ generates a subgroup of order $2$, given that $|\mathbb{Z}_{n}|$ is even $n = 2k$?

- $|G| = 2:\;\;$ If $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$, $D = \{0, 1\} = G$.
- $|G| > 2: \;\;k = d \;\; \implies\quad n = 2k = 2d \implies d = \dfrac{n}{2}.$

Try specific examples to get clear on what's going on here: What element in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, generates a subgroup of order $2$? Likewise, for $Z_{12}$ what is the element that generates a subgroup of order $2$?

Comment: Why aren't you using the notation with $+$ ? the group is abelian

Comment: @amWhy no thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome Anna!

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is cyclic and have a subgroup of order $l$ $\iff l\mid n$.
Moreover, this subgroup is unique.

In your case you want $l=2$ hence such a subgroup exist if and only
if $n$ is even.

You also want $H=\langle d\rangle$ hence the order of $d$ is $?$
hence $d=?$

Comment: @amWhy - True. I think that Brian's answer also uses Lagrange when he deduced $n$ is even.

Comment: @amWhy - but now you got me curious on how to do this without Lagrange ;)

Comment: My guess is that this question is a precursor to introducing Lagrange...and hence, in that context, is more of a challenge.

Comment: @amWhy where Brian is using Lagrange? + still not sure about d...

Comment: @Anna - How do you deduce $n$ is even without it ?

Comment: That's Ok, Belgi. +1

Comment: @Belgi ok the order of the subgroup is even so from lagrange the group order is even too. so n and d must be even

Comment: @Anna = How about $n=6,d=3$ ?

Comment: oops... I guess n divides d...

Comment: @Anna - $6$ does not divide $3$ (it's the other way around). Also - you can tell exactly what $d$ is.

Comment: @Belgi Im pretty bad at this:) but thank you for your patience. d = n/2

Comment: @Anna - yes, exactly! :)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You know that $2d\equiv 0\pmod n$, so $n$ has to be even, and $d$ has to be ... what?